# C# - Dealing with contradictions in string.replace

Tags: c#, string, replace

I'm getting started with C# and programming in general and I've been playing with the "if" statements, arrays and generally getting to grips with things. However, one thing that has stumped me is how you would go about performing an replace operation which is inherently contradictory.

IE: I have string "AAABBB" but I want to search through my text and replace all "A"s with "B"s and vice-versa. So my intended output would be "BBBAAA".

I'm currently trying to use string.replace and if statements but it's not working (it follows the order of the statements, so in the above examples I'd get all "A" or all "B".

Code examples:

```
if (string.Contains("a"));
{
    string = string.Replace("a", "b");
}

if (string.Contains("b"));
{
    string = string.Replace("b", "a");
}
```

Any help would be super welcome!

Comment: It would help if you'd give a *valid* code example (not using keywords as variable names), indent it, and give the output vs the expected output.

Comment: Look at **[foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx)**

Comment: Your problem is your algorithm, not the string.Replace - the results you are facing are expected result of your code example..

Comment: @rudolf_franek: As the question explains *why* it's not working (cf. "it follows the order of the statements"), I think the OP is aware of that and hence asking for a workaround.

Comment: Note that there's no regular expression involved in your code... you might want to remove the regex tag.

Comment: Good point, removed the tag.

Comment: Not entirely sure why you "check" if a string contains an `a` or `b`? Such tests will double running time (approximately).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using Linq:

```
s = new string(s.Select(x => x == 'A' ? 'B' : x == 'B' ? 'A' : x).ToArray());
```

Comment: This was the simplest way of achieving what I was going for in the little word game I'm creating, so thanks for this :)

Answer (score 10):

If you're always replacing one character with another, it's probably simplest to convert it to a `char[]` and go through it one character at a time, fixing each one appropriately - rather than doing "all the As" and then "all the Bs".

```
public static string PerformReplacements(string text)
{
    char[] chars = text.ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
    {
        switch (chars[i])
        {
            case 'A':
                chars[i] = 'B';
                break;
            case 'B':
                chars[i] = 'A';
                break;
        }
    }
    return new string(chars);
}
```

Comment: Dear diary, today Jon Skeet thanked me. My C# skills are stronger now.

Comment: Thanks, this is an interesting approach that I hadn't considered, it actually helps me with the next thing I was stumped on, so thanks a bunch!

Comment: @JonSkeet! It is such a neat solution.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why this fails is because all `A`'s are first replaced by `B`'s but then back to `A`'s.

A generic way to solve this is the following:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;

public class Foo {

    public static string ParallelReplace (string text, char[] fromc, char[] toc) {
        Contract.Requires(text != null);
        Contract.Requires(fromc != null);
        Contract.Requires(toc != null)
        Contract.Requires(fromc.Length == toc.Length);
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>().Length == text.Length);
        Array.Sort(fromc,toc);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(char c in text) {
            int i = Array.BinarySearch(fromc,c);
            if(i >= 0) {
                sb.Append(toc[i]);
            } else {
                sb.Append(c);
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

}
```

Demo with `csharp` interactive shell:

```
csharp> Foo.ParallelReplace("ABasdsadsadaABABB",new char[] {'b','a','s'},new char[] {'f','s','a'});
"ABsadasdasdsABABB"
```

This represents a mapping `{b->f,a->s,s->a}`. The method works in `O(s*log(n)+n*log(n))`, with `s` the length of the string and `n` the number of rules.

The `Contract`'s are not necessary, but can help if one uses a static code analysis tool to prevent making errors.

Comment: This is also very cool. Thanks for the example, I'll keep this generic method in mind for some of things I have lined up as it looks pretty handy.